# How to call action method of active record from active resource?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a web service and for that I made two applications called backend and frontend. Frontend is an active resource client and I want it to call custom action method of backend's controller from custom action method of frontend's controller. I am new in ROR.

**frontend controller**:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

 def my_method

    # call custom action of backend's controller 

 end
.....

end
```

**backend controller:**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

 def my_method

 # my code go here

 end

end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If ur dealing with this two application wouldn't be a better design make then front-end application interact with the back-end throw an API? I suggest you to take a look at [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activeresource/README_rdoc.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Call `ProductsController.my_method`  But better still, make it a `Products` Model and then call `Product.method`(any_params_you_want)